# Justify all subgroups of $U(n)$ is of the form $U_d(n)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the set $$U(n):=\{r\in \mathbb{N}: 1\leqslant r\leqslant n, (r,n)=1\}$$ is a multiplicative group of order $\phi(n)$, (Euler's phi function).

Now for any positive divisor $d$ of $n$, the set
$$U_d(n):=\{x\in U(n): x\equiv 1[d]\}$$
is a subgroup of $U(n)$.

> My question is, is every subgroup of $U(n)$ is of this form?

I know about cyclic subgroups of $U(n)$. But in that case, is there any way so that we can determine $d$ as the positive divisor of $n$ such that the cyclic subgroup will become $U_d(n)$?

The question clicked my mind because I was studying Sylow's theorem and according to Sylow's 1st theorem, $U(105)$ must have a subgroup of order $2^4$ since $|U(105)|=\phi(105)=48=2^4\cdot 3$ but unfortunately, I could not get any one. Then I was thinking about $U_d(n)$ and then came up with the current query.

Comment: Consider for example the subgroup of squares (or more generally $m^{\text{th}}$ powers) in $U(n)$.